# Redux returns error 'Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.' even though middleware is defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I would like to use redux-thunk for redux async action, but redux returns error: 'Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.'

I am not using webpack, instead of that I am concatenating all js files into one file. I am aware that my issue may be caused by that, but for now I need solution without webpack, if possible.

**Here is store definition**

```
const pricingStore = Redux.createStore(
    pricingReducer,
    Redux.applyMiddleware(window.ReduxThunk.default)
    // using UMD redux-thunk from https://npmcdn.com/redux-thunk@2.0.1/dist/redux-thunk.min.js
);

const {Provider} = ReactRedux;

$(document).ready(() => {
    const pricingContainer = document.getElementById('containerPricing');

    if (pricingContainer) {
        parsePricingData();
        const render = () => {
            ReactDOM.render(
                <Provider store={Redux.createStore(pricingReducer)}>
                    <Pricing />
                </Provider>,
                pricingContainer
            );
        };

        render();
        pricingStore.subscribe(render);
    }
});
```

**Here is action**

```
function uploadInvoices() {
    console.log('works here');

    return function () {
        console.log('doesnt log this msg');

        return null;
    };
}
```

**Here is call of action**

```
const { connect } = ReactRedux;

let FileUpload = ({dispatch}) => {
    return (
        <input type="file" name="image" multiple onChange={(e) => dispatch(uploadInvoices())} />
    );
};

FileUpload = connect()(FileUpload);
```

Please help me with solution

Answer (score 0):

> Actions are plain JavaScript objects. Actions must have a type
>   property that indicates the type of action being performed. Types
>   should typically be defined as string constants. Once your app is
>   large enough, you may want to move them into a separate module.

This is from the redux docs. It would seem that your issue is the from the fact that your action is returning something other than an object.

Just to clarify a bit more. The action is supposed to be doing nothing more than return an object that at the minimum has the type property passed to the reducer. If you want to use a thunk to handle async flow, this should happen BEFORE the action is called. The flow would be something more like this. Call redux thunk from your connected component, the thunk then dispatches the action and passes it any payload it may need. Finally the action will only return an object and have no logic of its own.